# Why numpy .isin function gives incorrect output

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

My requirement is I have a large dataframe with millions of rows. I encoded all strings to numeric values in order to use `numpys` vectorization to increase processing speed.

So I was looking at a way to quickly check if a number exists in another list column. Previously, I was using list comprehension with string values, but with after converting to `np.arrays` was looking at similar function.

I stumbled across this link: [check if values of a column are in values of another numpy array column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67158284/check-if-values-of-a-column-are-in-values-of-another-numpy-array-column-in-panda)

In order to the `numpy.isin`, I tried running below code:

```
dt = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'],
                   'col_a': [1,2,5,1,2],
                   'col_b': [2,2,[2,5,4],4,[1,5,6,3,2]]})
dt

    id  col_a   col_b
0   a   1       2
1   a   2       2
2   a   5       [2, 5, 4]
3   b   1       4
4   b   2       [1, 5, 6, 3, 2]
```

When I enter:

```
np.isin(dt['col_a'], dt['col_b'])
```

The output is:

```
array([False,  True, False, False,  True])
```

Which is incorrect as the 3rd row has 5 in both columns `col_a` and `col_b`.

Where as if I change the value to 4 as below:

```
dt = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'],
                   'col_a': [1,2,4,1,2],
                   'col_b': [2,2,[2,5,4],4,[1,5,6,3,2]]})

dt

    id  col_a   col_b
0   a   1       2
1   a   2       2
2   a   4       [2, 5, 4]
3   b   1       4
4   b   2       [1, 5, 6, 3, 2]
```

and execute same code:

```
np.isin(dt['col_a'], dt['col_b'])
```

I get correct result:

```
array([False,  True,  True, False,  True])
```

Can someone please let me know why it's giving different results.

Comment: 'vectorized' isn't possible. `colb` is object dtype containg a mix of numbers and lists that vary in length.

Comment: @hpaulj if `col_b` were to be all list columns but of varying lengths, would vectorization be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.isin` for each element from `dt['col_a']` checks whether it is present in the whole `dt['col_b']` column, i.e.:

```
[
   1 in dt['col_b'],
   2 in dt['col_b'],
   5 in dt['col_b'],
   ...
]
```

There's no `5` in `dt['col_b']` but there's `4`

From the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html)

> `isin` is an element-wise function version of the python keyword in. `isin(a, b)` is roughly equivalent to `np.array([item in b for item in a])` if `a` and `b` are 1-D sequences.

Also, your issue is that you have an inconsistent `dt['col_b']` column (some values are numbers some are lists). I think the easiest approach is to use apply:

```
def isin(row):
    if isinstance(row['col_b'], int):
        return row['col_a'] == row['col_b']
    else:
        return row['col_a'] in row['col_b']

dt.apply(isin, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Ah ok, can you please let me know if there's a vectorized approach to what I am trying to accomplish

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40175327/numpy-element-wise-in-operation) answers your question

Comment: I am getting this error : `ValueError: ('Shapes must match', (5,), (5, 1))`, can you please add that to the answer, I am very new to numpy

Comment: Is that vectorized operation? I need vectorized approach to make my code faster

Comment: If entire `col_b` was list column, would it possible to use any vectorized function?

Comment: @KarthikS Yes, see the link in my comment

Comment: getting same `Shapes must match` error. Is it because in the link the `X` and `y` variables are fixed size and in my case the list length in `col_b` is varying ?

Answer (score 1):

Since `col_b` not only has lists but also integers, you may need to use `apply` and treat them differently:

```
( dt.apply(lambda x: x['col_a'] in x['col_b'] if type(x['col_b']) is list 
                                             else x['col_a'] == x['col_b'], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool
```